# Why can't I access dynamic text within a CS4 compiled SWC?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a movieclip created in CS4. I export that into my Flex Project's /lib and then try to access the text. All the textfields have ids, embedded text, and show up in intellisense. But when i run the project, the textfield is blank. What is going on?

**Edit:** It appears to only not work when the text is **embedded**. Non embedded text works fine.

Comment: has a solution been found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Importing text objects and fonts embedded in swfs can have any number of weird embedding errors - in my experience it takes a lot of tweaking to get things right.  A few things to look at:

- are you embedding all of the
  characters?  Selective embedding
  might not be including the set of
  characters your trying to display. 
  For example, if the text is bold but
  you only embedded the normal version
  of the font, the characters won't
  show up.
- are you embedding the font correctly?
  Make sure it's embedding as a flash
  type font if you're exporting from
  Flash Authoring CS4, or triple-check
  your embed syntax if you're embedding
  in Flex.  One little typo can throw
  the whole thing off.
- Try exporting the movie clip from
  Flash Authoring CS4. Can you view the
  text there?  This will help you
  trouble shoot whether the problem is
  on the Flash Authoring CS4 side or
  the Flex side.

Hope that helps - embedded text can be a bit nasty.  If you can include more code or link to a swf we could try to play around with it a bit more and give you more information.